code as notebook, how to reload custom module?
See the example below:
#%% cell 1
import my_custom_module

#%% cell2:
data = load_data_that_takes_a_long_time_to_load()

#%% cell 3:

result = my_custom_module.function_that_changes(data)

How can I write a python script that has those cell separations so it can run programmatically as a regular python script, yet if I'm running cells manually, I need to be able to reload a module that changed without restarting the kernel. I've tried using importlib.reload but to no avail.

Does this answer your question? Reloading submodules in IPython

try IPython's %autoreload
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html

In a jupyter notebook, I see how to use the %autoreload alternative, but not on a .py file.
